# Async image in button issue

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a piece of code like this in my function. And I do a looping creating a async image inside the button.
But when I run it, my button do not show the async image.Please tell me what's wrong with my code.
When I print NSLog the url, its going well and show all of the image url.

```
            // ADD BUTTON
            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(topLeft.x,topLeft.y,width,height)];

            //Asyncronous Image
            NSMutableString *imageUrl;

            if ([[[type objectAtIndex:btnNumber] objectForKey:@"LAST_CONTENT_IMAGE"] isEqualToString:@""] || [[type objectAtIndex:btnNumber] objectForKey:@"LAST_CONTENT_IMAGE"] == nil) {
                imageUrl = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"bank_images/actual/"];
            }else{
                imageUrl = [[type objectAtIndex:btnNumber] objectForKey:@"LAST_CONTENT_IMAGE"];
            }

            NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
            NSLog(@"URL GBR : %@", url1);

            NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *stringSub = [imageUrl substringWithRange:NSMakeRange (imageUrl.length-9, 9)];
            NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%u_%@", documentsDirectory,[GlobalVariable sharedInstance].indexCategoryGlobal,stringSub];

            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
            {
                NSData *img = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
                UIImage *imageExist = [UIImage imageWithData:img];
                image = imageExist;
                [btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }else{
                dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0);
                dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                    //This is what you will load lazily
                    NSData   *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data1];
                        [btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                        if ([stringSub isEqualToString:@"s/actual/"]){
                            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_thumb.png"];
                            [btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }

                        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                                contents:data
                                                              attributes:nil];
                    });
                });
            }
            [btn setTag:btnNumber];
```

Comment: Are you aware of SDWebImage and if not go through this link:  https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: So that you can use directly [btn setImageWithUrl:];

Comment: thanks @venkat, but I prefer to use this code now.
Could you help me please without using that library?
:)

Comment: Where you are adding that btn to which View you are adding ??

Comment: I set a blank in the json and then it show default_thumb.png, so I think the problem is not from the view.

Comment: I think the button instance is nil in the dispatch block. Make button variable as __block level variable so that it will be accessible within the block.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you create NSURL object in a wrong way 
Apple documentation says us that

**URLWithString:**
Creates and returns an NSURL object initialized with a provided string.

- (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
  Parameters
  URLString
  The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808. (To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: instead.)

So, looks like you should use 
**fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:**

Comment: could you explain more specifics @vlad?

Comment: You have such code imageUrl = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"bank_images/actual/"];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]; Here @"bank_images/actual/" looks like a path in a file system. If so you should create NSURL object with method like NSURL *url1= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageURL];

Comment: Also it will be very helpful if you provide info what are you put into [[type objectAtIndex:btnNumber] objectForKey:@"LAST_CONTENT_IMAGE"]?

Comment: Also i don't understand what is the data var here [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:data attributes:nil]; where are you get it from? It should be a data1?